# RejectedAccessException: No such constructor found

Tags: java, kotlin, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a kotlin library, where class `Environment` is defined having constructor:

```
data class Environment @JvmOverloads constructor(val name : String, val host: String, val port: Int, val secureConn: Boolean=false,
                                                 val user : String = "user", val password : String = "defaultPass", val loginPath : String = "/login",
                                                 val trustStorePath: String = "/trustStore.jks", val trustStorePassword: String = "defaultPass",
                                                 val disableHostnameVerification: Boolean = true) { ...
```

I try to create an instance of this class at jenkins pipeline code:

```
def env = new Environment("name", "host", 7777, true, "username", "pass", "/login", "/cert.jks", "anotherPass", true)
```

Then i get following error:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: No such constructor found: new package.Environment java.lang.String java.lang.String java.lang.Integer java.lang.Boolean java.lang.String java.lang.String java.lang.String java.lang.String java.lang.String java.lang.Boolean
```

But there IS exactly such constructor! What could be the problem?

Also there is a decompiled version of kotlin sources. It seems it matches:

```
public Environment(@NotNull String name, @NotNull String host, int port, boolean secureConn, @NotNull String user, @NotNull String password, @NotNull String loginPath, @NotNull String trustStorePath, @NotNull String trustStorePassword, boolean disableHostnameVerification)
```

Comment: I think it's because of the default values in the constructor

Comment: I would use reflection to check in runtime what classes are loaded and what constructors are provided, but tbh I don't know much about how Jenkins handle this and if it is accessible from its scripts. It looks to me like it tries to load class with canonical name package.Environment. Is this what you really want?

Comment: @tim_yates Why? There is ```@jvmOverloads``` annotation, so bunch of constructors are generated. I can see it in the decompiled file, and there is the constructor which is needed. May be the problem is in type cast?

Comment: @qwaler afaik reflection is prohibited in jenkins sandbox
https://github.com/jenkinsci/script-security-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/scriptsecurity/sandbox/whitelists/blacklist >it tries to load class with canonical name package.Environment.Is this what you really want?
Yes, it is a class from a jar.

Comment: Did you try to disable this plugin? https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-32681

Comment: @mregulski I'll try, but most likely i will not be allowed to do this.  Btw i tried to call `Environment` constructor with first 3 arguments without default values, and it worked. Then i added next parameter, and it still works. Then i tried next, and so on. I see `RejectedAccessExeption` again when i try to pass `loginPath` parameter and going to investigate it.

Comment: What if the problem is about primitive types? I would try to add a question mark next to the type of Int and Boolean to enforce translating it to boxed types instead of primitives.

Comment: @mregulski It turned out that there really weren't such constructor. I used `Environment.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion()` in my pipeline and saw outdated version of the library i use, so jenkins got wrong version. It differs from version IDEA shows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233341/discussion-between-mregulski-and-redmurloc).